# Inject Reducers and Sagas asynchronously for React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a web application made from reactjs, redux and react-router where i used the code splitting technique to inject sagas and reducers asynchronously. Now that i want to use react native. I have come to know react navigation is the best bet in the game of routing. However i have no idea how can i inject sagas and reducers asynchronously like i have done with react router.

**routes.js**

```
import { getAsyncInjectors } from './utils/asyncInjectors';
import AppReducer from './containers/App/reducers';
import AppSagas from './containers/App/sagas';

const errorLoading = (err) => {
  console.error('Dynamic page loading failed', err); // eslint-disable-line no-console
};

const loadModule = (cb) => (componentModule) => {
  cb(null, componentModule.default);
};

export default function createRoutes(store) {
  // Create reusable async injectors using getAsyncInjectors factory
  const { injectReducer, injectSagas } = getAsyncInjectors(store); // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

  // We need these reducers and saga upfront
  injectReducer('global', AppReducer);
  injectSagas(AppSagas);

  return [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        const importModules = Promise.all([
          System.import('./containers/HomeScreen'),
        ]);

        const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);

        importModules.then(([component]) => {
          renderRoute(component);
        });

        importModules.catch(errorLoading);
      },
    },
  ];
}


export function injectAsyncReducer(store, isValid) {
  return function injectReducer(name, asyncReducer) {
    if (!isValid) checkStore(store);

    invariant(
      isString(name) && !isEmpty(name) && isFunction(asyncReducer),
      '(app/utils...) injectAsyncReducer: Expected `asyncReducer` to be a reducer function'
    );

    if (Reflect.has(store.asyncReducers, name)) return;

    store.asyncReducers[name] = asyncReducer; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
    store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.asyncReducers));
  };
}

export function getAsyncInjectors(store) {
  checkStore(store);

  return {
    injectReducer: injectAsyncReducer(store, true),
    injectSagas: injectAsyncSagas(store, true),
  };
}
```

How can i apply the same concept when using react navigation? And would this bring any benefit to the application initial load time?

Comment: Why you need to inject sagas or reducers asynchronously in react native? We do this in web app since we need to boost the time for initial load, but for native app, all the code will be downloaded on your device.

Comment: @talent this is absolutely not true. You can build web app as well with react native.